# implement Group by partly on a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

say I have the following dataframe:

| Location | Type | Take | Num |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| One | A | 2016-01-01 | 1 |
| One | B | 2016-01-01 | 2 |
| One | C | 2016-01-01 | 3 |
| One | A | 2016-01-01 | 4 |
| One | B | 2016-01-01 | 5 |
| One | C | 2016-01-01 | 6 |

I want to groupby the location and type and sum the Num values. I want to keep the Take col unchanged as follows:

| Location | Type | Take | Num |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| One | A | 2016-01-01 | 5 |
| One | B | 2016-01-01 | 7 |
| One | C | 2016-01-01 | 9 |

I have tried the following:

```
df=df.groupby(['Location','Type'], as_index = False).agg({'Num':'sum','Take':'first'})
```

It is not working and returning the following error:
TypeError: must be str, not int

Thanks in advance for any hint!

Comment: Working fine for me

Comment: You should probably check the types of every elements contained in your dataframe. This is most likely an error coming from a type that is inconsistent in either "Num" or "Take" IMO, but since we do not have the exact data you are using, can't really check it

Comment: I have just checked the info() of the data I have: 
all cols seems to be defined as Object

Answer (score 0):

Try this
df=df.groupby(['Location','Type', 'Take' ], as_index = False).agg({'Num':'sum'})